# How select tablename from user_table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have dinamics tables on my system, it change one number on the name so I do not have a fixed name. I wish to select the lasted table but only the name of the table to make a select to this table.

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT * FROM (select a.tablespace_name || '.' || a.table_name AS TABLE_NAME
from user_tables a
wherE a.tablespace_name='USERNAME'
and a.table_name like '%_DIN'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = '1'))
```

for example.
the table name of

```
SELECT * FROM (select a.tablespace_name || '.' || a.table_name AS TABLE_NAME
    from user_tables a
    wherE a.tablespace_name='USERNAME'
    and a.table_name like '%_DIN'
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC)
    WHERE ROWNUM = '1'
```

return:
7_DIN

is a name of one table in my tablespace
 I want to take this name and make a select of this table.

something like

```
select * from 7_DIN
```

All in one statement

Comment: You haven't really said what the problem is. Does it not find anything? Does it not find the right one? Do you really mean to be restricting by tablespace? Is there a fixed pattern - the number increments but is always four digits, say, and always in the same place in the string? Some sample data might help, as well as any error. Can you go by `created` instead? (Having multiple  tables like this doesn't seem like a nice way to do things).

Comment: If you try to do this query you have a value from the user_tables, no the content from the table on the system

Comment: Ah, right, I see what you're trying to do. You have to use some form of dynamic SQL. Where are you running the query from? It's easy in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer. Otherwise you will need to use PL/SQL.

Comment: I have plsql is an Oracle Database 10g

Comment: Yes, but what is the client - how is the query being run, from SQL*Plus, over JDBC, something else? What are you doing with the results, just displaying them?

Comment: it run in one view on oracle 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is code step-by-step, you can test it in [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/383545/1).

Sample tables used for test:

```
create table t1(n number)
/
create table t2(n number)
/
create table t13(n number)
/
insert into t1(n) values(1)
/
insert into t2(n) values(2)
/
insert into t13(n) values(13)
/
```

Declare types used as selection result, same as row type of tables with dynamic names:

```
create or replace type t_row as object(n number)
/
create or replace type t_rowlist as table of t_row
/
```

Function which searches for last table and selects data from them into collection, then returns collection as table data:

```
create or replace function get_last_data return t_rowlist
as
  v_table varchar2(30);
  v_rows  t_rowlist;
begin

  select table_name into v_table from (
    select * from user_tables where table_name like 'T%'
    order by lpad(substr(table_name,2),40,'0') desc
  )  
  where rownum = 1;

  execute immediate 'select t_row(n) from '|| v_table
  bulk collect into v_rows;

  return v_rows;

end;
/
```

Create view based on function data:

```
create or replace view last_data_view as
  select * from table(get_last_data)
/
```

This works good only if dynamic tables don't have a big amount of data.
Otherwise it's better to use pipelined functions. To do so, just replace function implementation with code below:

```
create or replace function get_last_data_pipe 
return t_rowlist pipelined
as
  v_table  varchar2(30);
  v_row    t_row;
  v_cursor sys_refcursor;
begin

  select table_name into v_table from (
    select * from user_tables where table_name like 'T%'
    order by lpad(substr(table_name,2),40,'0') desc
  )  
  where rownum = 1;

  open v_cursor for 'select t_row(n) from '|| v_table;

  loop
    fetch v_cursor into v_row;
    exit when v_cursor%notfound;
    pipe row(v_row);
  end loop;

  close v_cursor;

  return;
end;
```

[Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/164c3/1) to test SQLFiddle.